# From an electrochemical perspective, why do Li-ion batteries charge with constant-current and constant-voltage phases?

Tags: electrochemistry

I've recently been looking at battery charging and management circuits, and battery manufacturers often specify a constant-current, constant-voltage and sometimes even a startup phase to battery charging. I imagine there must be some electrochemical or materials science explanation for why this charging pattern is most desirable. Presumably, this method best preserves battery life/ suppresses unwanted phase transitions/ etc., but calls for a mechanistic explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The constant current phase controls and limits the heat released by charging. High temperature causes faster cell ageing by acceleration unwanted sidereactions. These are mainly reactions of trace metallic lithium with carbonate solvent, happening especially when almost charged.

The constant current phase monitors charging voltage and is stopped when it reaches the voltage threshold, determined by the manufacturer. This voltages should never be crossed. this happens typically at 70-80% of the current cell capacity. Sooner of aged cells due higher internal resistance.

After reaching voltage threshold, the charging pattern is switched to the constant voltage with the above threshold value. This phase ensures avoidance of side reactions like metallic lithium deposition, or irreversible oxidation on metal oxide electrode, deteriorating the cell and releases gases.

The cell charge is being topped until the charging current drops below chosen current threshold.

---

Feedback response:

CA-only charging brings constant controlled stress on being charged cells, but would end prematurely for Li-Ion cells.

CV-only charging would destroy or heavily damage Li-Ion cells, unless already at low enough current charging curve.

Those charging parameters are qualitatively general for all rechargeble cells. The optimal values for charging current ( in numerical multiples of capacity ) and max charging voltage ( or alternatively charging stop detections) differ across cell chemistries.

These data are better to get on cell manufacturer pages.

Even within Li-Ion/Pol cell family, there is multiple cell electrolyte + electrode chemistries and cell designs, focused on capacity, power or longevity, with various maximum current/capacity and voltage values. Some chemistries like NiCd/MH do not have strict voltage threshold, so charge stop detection is managed by different electronic ways, what is out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Any technical references for the optimality/ advantages of the CC-CV charging method you describe?

Comment: Feedback in answer extension.